# Replace string by matching a pattern in R

Tags: r, string

I have a tibble of strings.

`string <- tibble(METRIC = c('Eagle.PCT.Dominant', 'Eagle.PCT2.Dominant'))`

I want to find where the string contains a `.`, then a set of characters, then another `.`, and replace the two periods with `_`, so that `Eagle.PCT.Dominant` becomes `Eagle_PCT_Dominant` and `Eagle.PCT2.Dominant` becomes `Eagle_PCT2_Dominant`.

This is what I've tried:

```
string %>%
  mutate(newMETRIC = str_replace_all(METRIC, '\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.', '_[A-Za-z0-9]+_'))
```

But the replacement doesn't operate like a string/regex, it only replaces it as is, so that `Eagle.PCT.Dominant` becomes `Eagle_[A-Za-z0-9]+_Dominant` instead of `Eagle_PCT_Dominant`. Is there a way to replace the string so that it matches the pattern?

Comment: You need to capture the match and then insert the capture group into the output: `string %>% mutate(newMETRIC = str_replace_all(METRIC, '\\.([A-Za-z0-9]+)\\.', '_\\1_'))`

Comment: Thanks MrFlick! I'm getting an error that says "Trying to access the index that is out of bounds."

Comment: WHy not just this: `string %>%
  mutate(METRIC = str_replace_all(METRIC, "\\.", "_"))`?

Comment: Was that when you ran it on the above example? Or on other data? If I copy/paste from above, it works fine for me.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot the parantheses between the character class. That worked! You're the best, thank yoooooou!